# Unable to validate Microsoft cluster

Tags: windows-cluster

I have Microsoft windows cluster.
I have 2 nodes on **windows 2008 R2 SP1 Ent**.
both of them with Windows PowerShell 4 and with up to date with Windows updates

When I'm trying to do a validation to this cluster I get this error:

> Error: The action 'Validate This Cluster...' did not complete. There
> is an error in XML document (5, 73). Attempt by method
> 'Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderClusPrepConfig.Read4_Assemblies(Boolean,
> Boolean)' to access method
> 'MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Validation.TestAssemblyCollection.Add(MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Validation.TestAssembly)'
> failed.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide the results in the validation report?

Comment: Why are you building a new failover cluster with Windows Server 2008 R2?

Comment: I can't provide the results because the validation is not working. In addition we have an old cluster of win 2008 r2 and I just added a new node

Answer (score 0):

1. Open command prompt as administrator.
2. Type "powershell -version 2.0"
3. execute your Test-Cluster command.

Comment: same issue: Test-Cluster : There is an error in XML document (5, 73).
    Attempt by method 'Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderClusPrepConfig.Read4_Assembl
ies(Boolean, Boolean)' to access method 'MS.Internal.ServerClusters.Validation.TestAssemblyCollection.Add(MS.Internal.S
erverClusters.Validation.TestAssembly)' failed.